# Correct process for upgrading an Ember-cli addon

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-addon

What is the correct process for upgrading an Ember-cli addon? If I follow the normal process for upgrading an ember app:

```
npm uninstall -g ember-cli
npm cache clean
bower cache clean
npm install -g ember-cli@0.1.15
rm -rf node_modules bower_components dist tmp
ember install:npm ember-cli@0.1.15
ember install
ember init
```

It will replace the brocfile with `ember-app` instead of `ember-addon`. Will this let it still work as an addon?

Comment: I assume you mean this line at the top of the Brocfile? `var EmberAddon = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-addon');` The [addon blueprint still has that content in the Brocfile](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/blob/v0.1.15/blueprints/addon/files/Brocfile.js#L4) so it sounds like ember-cli doesn't know it's in an addon directory. Does your addon have have `"keywords": ["ember-addon"]` in the package.json file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[It looks like](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/pull/3622/files) this has been taken care of in Ember-cli master. Mr. Penner [says he's trying](https://twitter.com/stefanpenner/status/580451304960585729) to get Ember CLI 0.2.2 out the door. That should fix your issue.

**Edit:** I can confirm 0.2.2 will fix this. Just pulled Ember-cli master and ran an update on one of my addons.